# Estimating the true error rate from the optimistic resubstitution (or apparent) error rate of a PLS-DA model

Tags: machine-learning, error, discriminant-analysis

In short, I'm trying to calculate the 'Upper bound 3' [Ref, p.4] of the *true error rate* for my partial least squares regression model (PLS-DA), separating two classes A and B of a sample set. Let me try to be specific.

In the context of linear discriminant analysis, I'm trying to estimate the *true error rate* of a linear discriminant prediction model $\alpha$ given its *apparent error rate* (or *resubstitution error estimate*) using the formula below from the reference. To do this, I have a sample set of known observations $\{x_{1,...,l},\omega_{1,...,l}\}$ consisting of measurements $x$, and class belonging $\omega=\{A,B\}$ of size $l=308$.

The unknown probability of a prediction error of my classifier $\alpha$ is $P(\alpha)$ and the *error frequency* in the training sample i.e. the *apparent error rate* is $v(\alpha) = \frac{1}{l}\sum_{j=1}^{l}I_{\{\alpha(x_j)\neq\omega_j\}}$, where the summated term $I$ is the event that my classifier $\alpha$, based on the data $x$ classifies $\omega$ wrong.

Then, with the probability $1-\eta$ the upper bound of $P(\alpha)$ is [Ref, p.4]:

$P(\alpha) \leq \frac{1}{1+2q}\left(v(\alpha)+q+\sqrt{q^2 +2qv(\alpha) - 2qv(\alpha)^2} \right)$,

where $q=\frac{1}{l}\ln \left( \frac{N}{\eta} \right)$.

So far, I think I know everything except for $N$; my *apparent error rate* is tested to be $v(\alpha)=17\%$ by training a PLS regression model and testing it on the same set of $l=308$ observations, and I choose $\eta = 0.05$. **Now, what is $N$?**

I have some explanations from the reference which I do not understand:

The reference writes the following definition of N [Ref, p.1]:

> We have a set of decision rules which in this paper is supposed to be of finite size $N$, $\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_N \}$,

and in a set of examples, $N$ is calculated to $N=10^6$, $10^{12}$, or $10^{24}$ with the description [Ref, p.6]:

> This corresponds to the number of possible histogram discrimination rules when they are 2 classes and when the number of cells is equal to 20, 40 and 80 respectively; this also corresponds almost exactly to the number of possible classification trees with 2 classes, 35 binary variables and depth smaller than 2, 3 and 4 respectively.

To which I've noted that $2^{20}\approx 10^6$, $2^{40}\approx 10^{12}$, and $2^{80}\approx 10^{24}$, indicating some kind of combinatorics.

Can someone please help me understand what $N$ is, or point me in the direction of understanding it. I've read the reference thoroughly and looked at some of its citations, but I lack the understanding necessary. As a consequence, I do not know what further information is required from my part, to which you are welcome to ask anything!

Thank you for any help!

[Ref] Distribution-free performance bounds with the resubstitution error estimate by Olivier Gascuel and Gilles Caraux, [download pdf](https://www.lirmm.fr/content/download/6322/119759/file/GC-PRL-92.pdf).

Comment: I'll have to read the paper in detail, but I'm deeply suspicious how much meaningful information about generalization performance can be retrieved from resubstitution/autoprediction in practice. There is no bound on overfitting other than that (apparent) error cannot be below 0. Meanwhile, if you are looking for confidence intervals for more direct estimates of generalization error (cross validation/out-of-bootstrap/resampling and test set estimates), let me know and I'll point you to relevant literature.

Comment: You share the suspicion of my reviewer, I hear! I have other tests related to cross-validation and test set estimates that are close to the resubstitution in performance, albeit lower as they are not overfitted. I feel it would be very nice to have several tests supporting each other, and with a measurement of overfitting from above I could clearly show the problems with resubstitution in a pedagogical way.

Comment: As I am using PLS-DA, I only have 1 discriminant rule; the summation of my weighted variables vs. some threshold. Does this imply that for 2 classes I only have 1 so called 'cell' meaning N = 2^1? I'm not at all sure about this comment.

Comment: Some progress but not an answer (it may be very helpful if you could find the Vapnik book the paper cites - I couldn't, apparently there's a 2nd edition out and that seems to be *very* different from the first. E.g. it doesn't have 6 chapters, so no theorems 6.x :-/ ). Still I suspect that N is closely related to VC dimensionality. And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension#In_statistical_learning_theory gives a somewhat different bound by Vapnik (but the citation link doesn't work...). Interesting is the "small-print": that this is applicable only if no. training cases >> VC dimension

Comment: ... in other words, if there's no or not much danger of overfitting. For PLS-DA, you'll need to take into account a) the degrees of freedom of the latent variable projection and b) that your input is not just binary but probably continuous. Again, these are not ready thoughts, but intuitively I'd say that while PLS is a regularization, the dimensionality of PLS-DA won't be *that* much below a linear separation in original data space. Which is probably high, since that's when PLS is used. Think of it: your PLS-DA model has p x (number of latent variables + 1 [for centering]) coefficients to ...

Comment: ... calculate the scores, and then number of latent variables coefficients for the direction of the discriminant plus a threshold. All these need to be estimated (true, with regularization, but still). From a practical point of view, overfitted PLS models are not unheard of. As for b), you may argue that the continuous inputs have only a finite resolution, so you get something corresponding to the histogram bins in the paper. But for a 32bit sensor readout, you'd have 2^32 bins already for only a single variate...

Comment: In any case, I'd be interested to know what you ultimately find!

Comment: I recognize the arguments @cbeleites make about VC dimensionality, and I too think I need to find that book if I am to understand that particularly difficult (to me) subject. Regarding your comments about PLS, in my particular implementation of PLS the dimensionality is reduced 1; 1 principal component to separate the quite overlapping classes A and B in my study. (I guess +1 for centering as well). This reduction to 1 (possibly 2) dimensions is what I believe the author referes to as "cells" of what he calls histogram discrimination rules.

Comment: I've access to both the Vapnik references (I think), and neither the 2nd edition of the book nor the other Vapnik reference seems to have 6th chapter theorems. Perhaps this is more suitable as a chat @cbeleites? As I just created this account (forgot my old) I can't start one, could you, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a brief communication with the author of the paper (Olivier Gascuel), I received the explanation below. In short: PLS-DA predicts a value between 0 and 1, which classifies the observation by comparing the value to a threshold: all values above the threshold, e.g. 0.5, are classified as of class 1, else 0. As the threshold, 0.5 could be chosen continuously with infinite precision, the value of N is infinite as well. This means that the paper I provided by O. Gascuel is not fit for my intended use. Comments regarding Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimensionality by @cbeleites are supported by Olivier.

> Dear Linus, that’s an ancient paper… but basically this paper deals with the case where the number of classifiers is finite (e.g. decision trees with categorical variables). In the (usual) case where the number of classifiers is infinite (e.g. linear discrimination, as the weights are continuous and infinitely many) another approach must be used, typically based on the Vapnik-Chervonenkis (VC) dimension. But since 1992 I’m pretty sure that new approaches have been proposed, especially in the recent period with the incredible mood for machine learning. Hope this helps, regards, Olivier.